# How to set preselected the 10 first values on PHP into multiple select tag

Tags: php, ajax, append

I have this Ajax call and I'm getting back an array. I have insert the elements into the multiple select.
Until now the preselected values are ALL but I want to preselect only the 10 first values of this.
I know that it's missing something on this line

```
sel.append('<option value=" ' + getOb[i]["ObN"] + ' " selected>' + getOb[i]["Ob"] + '</option>');
```

but I do not know what is missing. Some help :)

```
$.ajax({
                            url: "data/jjj.php?call=sss"
                            , type: 'POST'
                            , success: function (getOb) {
                                if (getOb != null) {
                                    var sel = $("#mf123_ob");
                                    for (var i = 0; i < getOb.length; i++) {
                                        sel.append('<option value=" ' + getObjekte[i]["ObN"] + ' " selected>' + getObjekte[i]["Ob"] + '</option>');
                                    }
                                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your index to determine whether it should be selected or not:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < getOb.length; i++) {
    sel.append('<option value="' + getObjekte[i]["ObN"] + '"' + (i < 10 ? ' selected' : '') + '>' + getObjekte[i]["Ob"] + '</option>');
}
```

Or with string interpolation instead of concatenation:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < getOb.length; i++) {
    sel.append(`<option value="${getObjekte[i]["ObN"]}"${i < 10 ? ' selected' : ''}>${getObjekte[i]["Ob"]}</option>`);
}
```

I used a ternary expression `i < 10 ? ' selected' : ''` directly in the string, though you could also create a variable that hold this value beforehand and then use it when building your string.